# Display Loader while AngularJS retrieves data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an AngularJS controller that retrieves data from Firebase like this

```
angular
       .module('eventApp', ['ngSanitize'])
       .controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
           firebase.database().ref('/Events').once('value', function(snap) {
               $scope.$apply(function() {
                   var zz = snap.val()
                   $scope.events = zz;
               })
           })
       }])
```

I do `ng-repeat` for the collections in the view, but at the beginning the array `$scope.events` is empty. Therefore, I need to show a loader while data retrieval has not finished.

Do I use Promises?

PS: I am not using AngularFire

Comment: What type of loader you want to show ?

Comment: Let's just say a gif, for starters!

Comment: You can just maintain a flag to show loader then. Just set it true before firebase request and set it false after a response from firebase.

Comment: you can try `<div ng-if="!events>loading..</div>"` and if events is a array of objects, then define a $scope.events = [], and do something like `ng-if="!events.length"`

Comment: Using `$scope.flag` before and after Firebase request did the trick for me. Thanks!